proof that $K((x)) = \operatorname{Frac}(K[[x]])$
I want to show $K((x)) = \operatorname{Frac}(K[[x]])$, i.e. K((x)) is the minimum field containing $K[[x]]$, where the latter is an integrity domain, since it is a commutative ring and has no zero divisors (the coefficients of each polynomial belong to a field).
We must then show that if $f \in K((x))$ then $f=\frac{h}{g}$ with $f, g \in K[[x]]$, first of all i consider
$$K((x))=\{f=\sum_{i \in \Bbb Z_{\geq \alpha}} a_i t^i: a_i \in K, \alpha \in \mathbb Z \}$$
And
$$K[[x]]=\{f=\sum_{i =0}^{\infty} a_i t^i: a_i \in K \}$$
If $f \in K((x))$ and $\alpha \geq 0$, clearly $f \in K[[x]]$ and I suppose that such an element can be expressed as a quotient, starting from the fact that the coefficients of each polynomial belong to a field; I really don't see clearly how to approach the proof, any suggestions?

As you said, if you know that $K((x))$ is a field (more on that below), you only have to show that $K((x))$ lies inside $\operatorname{Frac}(K[[x]])$. Let $f \in K((x))$ as in your description, if the lowest degree (often called valuation) of $f$ is non-negative, then $f \in K[[x]] \subseteq \operatorname{Frac}(K[[x]])$ (you can write it as $\frac{f}{1}$ if you insist on vewing it as a fraction).
Now if $f$ has valuation $-\alpha <0$, notice that $x^{\alpha} f \in K[[x]]$, and if you denote the latter by $g$, this shows that $f = \frac{g}{x^{\alpha}} \in \operatorname{Frac}(K[[x]])$.
Now unless I understood the question wrong, I would say that what you asked is not really the trickiest part of showing $K((x)) = \operatorname{Frac}(K[[x]])$: so far, we assumed that $K((x))$ is a field, but that is not at all obvious that if $f$ is a power series in $K((x))$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ can also be written as such ! In other words, it is not obvious that every element of $K((x))$ has an inverse in that ring.
If you already know how to show this, great ! If not, here is a tip: by factoring cleverly, you can reduce to showing that $\frac{1}{1-\sum_{i \ge 1} a_i t^i1}$ lies again in $K[[x]]$. To do this, recall the power series expansion of $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Thank you for your contribution, there is only one detail that I did not understand and that is because $x^{\alpha} f \in K[[x]]$ (i suppose that $f \in K((x))$)

$f$ is a power series of the form $a_{-\alpha}x^{-\alpha} +a_{-\alpha+1}x^{-\alpha+1} + ...$, where I assume $-\alpha<0$. Multiplying by $x^{\alpha}$, you get $x^{\alpha}f = a_{-\alpha} + a_{-\alpha+1}x + ...$, which is an element of $K[[x]]$. Multiplying by $x^{\alpha}$ has the effect of "normalizing" the valuation of $f$ at 0.

On a concrete example, if $f = \frac{1}{x} + 1 +x$, we are just saying that $xf = 1 + x + x^2$ is in $K[[x]]$.
